# How does FindInstance work?

Tags: programming

I was asked a question one day: find an integer n such that the first five digits of 5*7^n is 12345.
It's very nice that I can quickly write code like this:

```
Block[{n=1,x=5},
  While[RealDigits[x=7.*x][[1,;;5]]!={1,2,3,4,5},n++];
  n]//Timing

{55.86399999999998,456370}
```

It takes less than a minute.
Later, I found that using the function `FindInstance` I could find a solution in much less time (but not the minimal solution):

```
FindInstance[{m+Log[10,1.2345]<Log[10,5.]+n Log[10,7.]<m+Log[10,1.2346],n>0},{m,n},Integers]//Timing

{0.3119999999999869,{{m->12872681,n->15232174}}}
```

Furthermore, I modified the code to be able to find the minimal solution like this:

```
 NestWhileList[
      n/.FindInstance[{m+Log[10,1.2345]<Log[10,5.]+n Log[10,7.]<m+Log[10,1.2346],First@#>n>0},{m,n},Integers]&,
      n/.FindInstance[{m+Log[10,1.2345]<Log[10,5.]+n Log[10,7.]<m+Log[10,1.2346],n>0},{m,n},Integers],
      #!={}&]//Timing

    {11.872000000000007,{{15232174},{15188314},{10277666},{5410878},{2955299},{499720},
{497170},{496660},{496150},{494620},{493090},{492580},{492070},{490540},{490030},{489520},{489010},{478300},{456370},n}}
```

The time it takes is one fifth of that classic method. So, I found a new way to solve this class of questions (just in Mathematica)?
My question is, can this method be used for other questions, and which mathematical method does the function `FindInstance` exactly use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `FindInstance` isn't very fast but sequental evaluation with `While` is very slow. Of course, `FindInstance` use some optimization. However, I can optimize even more

```
Pick[#, UnitStep[
     Log[10, 1.2346/1.2345] - 
      FractionalPart[Log[10, 5./1.2345] + # Log[10, 7.]]], 1] &@
  Range[1000000] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.051233, {456370, 456880, 457390, 457900, 458410, 458920, 459430, 
>     459940, 460450, 460960, 461470, 461980, 462490, 463000, 463510, 
>     464020, 464530, 465040, 465550, 466060, 466570, 467080, 467590, 
>     468100, 468610, 469120, 469630, 470140, 470650, 471160, 471670, 
>     472180, 472690, 473200, 473710, 474220, 474730, 475240, 475750, 
>     476260, 476770, 477280, 477790, 478300, 478810, 479320, 479830, 
>     480340, 480850, 481360, 481870, 482380, 482890, 483400, 483910, 
>     484420, 484930, 485440, 485950, 486460, 486970, 487480, 487990, 
>     488500, 489010, 489520, 490030, 490540, 491050, 491560, 492070, 
>     492580, 493090, 493600, 494110, 494620, 495130, 495640, 496150, 
>     496660, 497170, 497680, 498190, 498700, 499210, 499720}}

It test first 1000000 values of `n`. For comparison the approach with `While` takes 12 sec on my machine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Could you explain in brief why your code works so fast ( or why mine is slow )? Is there any aritifice to do with this class of questions?

Comment: @pencil This method works fast because it operates with [packed arrays](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array). `FindInstance` use unknown proprietary algorithm. Perhaps it is slower because it find pair of tho integers (n,m) instead of one integer.